# Repo url in order to merge changes

Tags: git

I have looked all around and I couldn't find any questions related specifically to this.

---

The way I clone a branch is to go to it's root repo location, so for example,

https://blah@onestash.company.com/scm/cc/batch.git

which has the following branches: `master`, `branchA` and `branchB`. Then I chose `branchA` to clone into my local.

---

I have cloned `branchA` into my local working space and now I want to merge my changes from `branchA` into `branchB`. I have `branchB` checked out into my local machine and I am currently under the local directory that this currently lives in. Now I want to merge `branchA` to `branchB`, however, how will do I get the repo URL for `branchB` so that I can do a `git merge`? In svn, it provides a repo URL for each branch but that doesn't seem to be the case in git.

Comment: Are you cloning different branches to different paths on disk? That's not how people usually use git.

Comment: Which command are you using for cloning?

Comment: You don't clone branches, you clone a remote (only one URL). You might want to read up about Git as there are many differences from SVN in operation and workflow.

Comment: @OliviaRuth Yes. Each branch that I clone will live under workspace folder and under workspace folder will have all the git clones

Comment: @OliviaRuth as far as I understand, he is talking about one single local repo. And if that's the case, there's no need to provide a url. You can refer to remote branch when merging:

```git merge -m "Merging from branch B" the-remote/branchB```

Comment: Ok.... from another of @robben comments: I think you are assuming that branches work the same way on svn and on git: there's a full url to reach a branch (and branches are no different from directories). That's _not correct_ for git. in git branches and directories are completely different things.... and, as has been stated already, when you clone a repo, you get all branches locally (associated to the remote: the-remote/master, the-remote/branchA, the-remote/branchB).

Answer (score 1):

Most git workflows involve cloning the repo locally to a single path and switching branches within that working copy.

You can use `git checkout branchName` to switch branches. Merging should be as simple as `git merge branchA`.

Highly recommend [the git book](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2d) for new users. It really helps to dig in and learn the concepts well. A lot of things are named similarly to svn concepts, but thinking of them the same can make things harder.

Comment: The book from git-scm is what I used to dive into git. Highly recommended. @OliviaRuth, there's already a newer version of the book. https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2 You like V1 better perhaps?

Comment: Hi Olivia, so I have done what you recommended. I have cloned the repo locally and I did a `git checkout branchB` and it was able to switch fine. However, when I am on the `branchB` directory and I do `git merge branchA` it says `"merge: branchA - not something we can merge"`

Comment: Do BranchA and BranchB share any common history at all?

Comment: Sounds like `branchA` does not exist in the repo you are working in.

Comment: try with ```git merge origin/branchA```

Comment: Actually when I did a `git checkout branchA` to switch and then did merge it worked.

Comment: But now i want to see the local changes in my windows explorer. However, when I go to the folder directory in my windows explorer where i cloned that repo it only shows the master branch. How can I see the changes it has done to branchA in my windows explorer?

Comment: Also, when I do `git merge branchA` and then do a `git status` it says "your branch is ahead by 4 commits" even though I nevered committed anything. Should my merge changes be under unstaged ?